# Program Error: "Instruction #1 Failed"

Tags: solana-program

What should I do when I withdraw pyth from lbank to phantom and it says Program Error: "Instruction #1 Failed"?

https://solscan.io/tx/w648kZ9AmKsVreYwbkgNgSW3fFo4kZwsdUqU1xM8soDEkVPfv4x3HY7hEMovNENUJVwE4zDbibV9vNfMHtAwXkv